# Running shutter command using cron

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, cron

The shutter program do screenshots. I wrote a bash script test.sh

`#!/bin/bash
shutter -f --web="any URL" -o '~/Dir1/%F-%T.png' -e`

Then I changed permissions of the test.sh file. Inserted the script in ~/bin directory. This directory wrote in the PATH variable. The script is running well, but in crontab not working.
I tried in several ways.

```
***** shutter -f --web=https://www.youtube.com -o '~/Dir1/%F-%T.png' -e 
***** exec shutter -f --web=https://www.youtube.com -o '~/Dir1/%F-%T.png' -e 
***** path of script
```

Comment: My first thought is that `$DISPLAY` is not set.

Comment: Both of the classic cron pitfalls are here: 1) Assuming environment variables that probably aren't there ($DISPLAY, $PATH), and 2) Didn't use full paths (assuming $PATH again).

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your script in the next way:

```
#!/bin/bash
export DISPLAY=:0
/usr/bin/shutter -f --web="any URL" -o '~/Dir1/%F-%T.png' -e
```

`echo $DISPLAY` will show you what you need to set instead of `:0` if required

Cron:

```
* * * * * fullpathtoscript
```

Also, check script is working by executing it.

I do not have ability to install `shutter` that is available in xenial and could not be installed using its repository source on my system. But I've done something similar using the next script:

```
!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/gnome-screenshot --display=:0
echo "screenshot have been taken" | logger
```

It works and images appear in pictures directory:

```
$ journalctl -f | grep screenshot
бер 10 17:36:02 lenovo user[9570]: screenshot have been taken
```